# Pivot a dataframe longer by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  Partner.A.s.ID = c(1101, 1102),
  Partner.A.s.name = c("X", "A"),
  Partner.B.s.ID = c(2101, 2102),
  Partner.B.s.name = c("Y", "B"),
  Partner.A.s.email = c("XXX", "AAA"),
  Partner.B.s.email = c("YYY", "BBB")
)
```

How can I pivot longer by group (i.e. combining A and B)? This is the desired output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  Partner.ID = c(1101, 1102, 2101, 2102),
  Partner.name = c('X', 'A', 'Y', 'B'),
  Partner.email = c("XXX", "AAA", "YYY", "BBB")
)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(tidyr)

example <- data.frame(
  Partner.A.s.ID = c(1101, 1102),
  Partner.A.s.name = c("X", "A"),
  Partner.B.s.ID = c(2101, 2102),
  Partner.B.s.name = c("Y", "B"),
  Partner.A.s.email = c("XXX", "AAA"),
  Partner.B.s.email = c("YYY", "BBB")
)

pivot_longer(example, everything() , 
             names_to = c("A/B",".value"),
             names_pattern = "Partner.(.).s.(.*)")


#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>   `A/B`    ID name  email
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 A      1101 X     XXX  
#> 2 B      2101 Y     YYY  
#> 3 A      1102 A     AAA  
#> 4 B      2102 B     BBB
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>